# How can I mapping hotkey between eclipse and Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am beginner with using Intellij. Nonetheless, I have used eclipse IDE for a long time. So, how can I mapping between hotkey's eclipse and hotkey's Intellij?

Comment: Don't try to make Intellij Eclipse.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: what is your mean?

Comment: @user3205761 you can go File -> Settings -> Keymap and set it into Eclipse, if you want to use eclipse keyboard shortcuts in intelliJ. :))

Comment: @Supun Wijerathne: I know that (Netbeans alo has the option), bro. However, I want to use default hotkey on IDEA :)

Comment: @user3205761 then u r all good. (Y) (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer that is good reference. For anyone like me:
[image]
refer: https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-intellij-idea-as-an-eclipse-user/4/

Comment: I probably misunderstood what you're asking; I thought you were trying to customize Intellij's to mimic Eclipse's mappings. I see now you're asking for the equivalent mappings.